# how to tell the application it was started from boot up of the device?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

Hi I'm writing a application for android that is started from boot up and i wondered if there was a way of telling the application it was started from the boot up of the device? i need it to do something different if the application was manual started (i.e not when the device was started). i am using a BroadcastReceiver to start the application when the device starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either make two different broadcast receivers one that has [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) for the intent filter, and another that has the other intent filter that you would use.

Or create one broadcastreceiver that has two intent filters like:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                               
        </intent-filter> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SOMETHING_ELSE"/>                               
        </intent-filter>         
    </receiver>
```

and then in the `onReceiver` do:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
  // do code for phone just powered on
} else {
  // do code for phone is already on
}
```

**EDIT**:
The above assumes that you use the `BroadcastReceiver` under two circumstances, which may not be the case judging from your question.

So if you are starting an `Activity` (or service), then in the `BroadcastReceiver` code, you could do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
i.putExtra("STARTED_FROM_BOOT", true);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Then in the activity, you could do:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("STARTED_FROM_BOOT")){
   // do your code for when started from boot.
}
```

Let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: Before the startActivity(i), you will also need  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 0):

yes, hook a `broadcastreceiver` with a on `boot completed` intent in the manifest and when the device boots up that receiver will be fired and you can do whatever you want there

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                               
        </intent-filter>         
    </receiver>
```

Comment: which is what he's already doing presumably when it starts after boot